# Why isn't a given relation a function from A to A?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

I'm having some difficulties solving the question below

> Let $A = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and $C = \{P, Q, R \}$.
>
> - Why isn't $\{\langle P, P \rangle, \langle Q, R \rangle, \langle R, Q \rangle, \langle R, R \rangle\}$ a function from $C$ to $C$?
> - Why isn't $\{\langle 1, 2 \rangle, \langle 2, 3 \rangle, \langle 3, 4 \rangle\}$ a function from $A$ to $A$?

How can you solve a question like this?

Thank you

Comment: There are some things a relation needs to satisfy in order to be a function. Check them one at a time to see which one fails for each of those relations.

Comment: Dabbish, please review the changes I made to your question, and perhaps try to learn from them.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I checked them one at a time if i'm correct, f(Q) = R and f(R) = Q does not satisfy from C to C, is this correct?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by satisfying "from $C$ to $C$", but the thing you write there is not what makes it not a function (at least not by itself).

Comment: hmm, I would appreciate if you could give me an example or hint

Comment: The answer by Asaf has some very good hints at what you need to do.

Comment: @Dabbish: Look again at your first relation; if you call it $f$, how does your claim that $f(R)=Q$ fit with the fact that $\langle R,R\rangle\in f$?

Answer (score 2):

Recall the definition. If $f\subseteq X\times X$, then $f$ is a function from $X$ to $X$ if the following things hold:

1. For every $x\in X$ there exists some $y$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in f$.
2. If $\langle x,y\rangle$ and $\langle x,z\rangle$ are both in $f$, then $y=z$.

In both the examples, only one of these properties hold.